# is there a way to link the created_by field that gets auto generated to users (create a relation) rather than it being related to the admin Users?

Tags: strapi

I'm new to Strapi tried creating a new collection and updating a value using postman for my endpoint.

The problem I'm having is that the "*created_by*" field seems to get auto-generated and will not allow me to update it using a created user credentials/id but it always picks the admin id.

I'm lost on this how can you relate the "created_by" field to your defined users rather than the admin table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### You shouldn't use "*created_by*" field.

### You need a relation field between users and collection

**Such as :**

```
Relation with User (from: users-permissions)
```

[image: relation with user]

---

Please check this "many to one relation" example.

[image: many to one relation example]

So `projectroot\api\bird\models\bird.settings.json` will have the following lines:

```
"user": {
      "via": "birds",
      "plugin": "users-permissions",
      "model": "user"
    },
```